# In python how to update psql Table column from updated peewee schema

Tags: python, database-migration, psql, peewee

I have a tabe in `psql` database with following property:

`author_ids = ArrayField(null=False)`

I want to update this table's column with following property:

`author_ids = ArrayField(IntegerField, null=False, index=True)`

I am using Peewee's migration but there is nothing for updating columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there is no API in [Schema Migrations](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations) for modifying a column's type. But from [`ArrayField`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#ArrayField), I'd say the default is already `IntegerField`, so no change here.

This leaves `index = True` as the only change, which is covered by [`add_index`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#SchemaMigrator.add_index).